# Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I had this error in my project. However couldn't find anywhere how to resolve it. Anyone has this problem?

It causes the build being run all over again every time.

Compilation with Kotlin compile daemon was not successful

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.IncrementalCompilationOptions.<init>(ZLjava/util/List;Ljava/util/List;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/String;ILorg/jetbrains/kotlin/daemon/common/CompilerMode;Lorg/jetbrains/kotlin/daemon/common/CompileService$TargetPlatform;[Ljava/lang/Integer;I[Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;Z)V
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.incrementalCompilationWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:258)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:207)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:156)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.compileWithDaemonOrFallback(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.KotlinCompilerRunner.runCompiler(KotlinCompilerRunner.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompiler(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:382)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.execute(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could not connect to kotlin daemon. Using fallback strategy.

Comment: Which versions of Gradle and Kotlin are you using?

Comment: @yole I'm using Kotlin 1.2.21 and Gradle 4.3.1 (also tried with Gradle 4.6 and 4.1 but the problem persists)

Comment: Looks like some misconfiguration, like multiple kotlin plugins in the classpath, or something like this. Gradle debug output may shed some light on it, e.g. the content of a line containing "[KOTLIN] Kotlin compiler classpath:" string.
It may make sense to file an issue in the kotlin issue tracker as well.

Comment: In my case bumping Kotlin version to *1.2.41* solved the issue

Answer (score 9):

Increasing heap space of Gradle JVM worked for me

To do this add (1000 MiB in this example)

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1000m
```

to your `gradle.properties` file.

If there is no `gradle.properties` in your project just create one near `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts`

Answer (score 3):

Make changes in Gradle.properties

make the JVM 1024 or 512 as required(for me 1024 works fine always);

then Make these changes in the app-level Gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    
        implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    }
    
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

> This worked for me

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.caching=true

extra-gen-snapshot-options=--obfuscate
```

Comment: Which part of it exactly worked for you? Where exactly did you put that configuration? What do those options do? Please don't just copy paste code and say it worked for you. Something in that configuration may be incompatible with the user's config.